# How to get the simple border line and boundary line between columns?

Tags: two-column

I am writing solution manual for students.

I am using LaTeX with `geometry`

```
\documentclass[landscape,twocolumn,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage[landscape,twocolumn]{geometry}
%\usepackage{tikz-cd}
%\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{amused}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
%\usepackage{eureka}
%\def\principaladviser#1{\gdef\@principaladviser{#1}}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
%\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{breqn}
%\usepackage{verbatim}
%\usepackage{apst-all}
%\usepackage{xy-pic}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
%\usepackage{dsfont}\let\mathbb\mathds
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[arrow,frame,matrix]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{eqlist}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{mwe}
%\usepackage{breqn}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
%\theoremstyle{plain}
%\newtheorem{Thm}{Theorem}[section]
%\newtheorem{lem}[Thm]{Lemma}
%\newtheorem{pro}[Thm]{Proposition}
%\newtheorem{de}[Thm]{Definition}
%\newtheorem{re}[Thm]{Remark}
%\newtheorem{ex}[Thm]{Example}
%\newtheorem{cor}[Thm]{Corollary}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\aug{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\!\!\!\fbox{\strut}\!\!\!}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{Thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[Thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{pro}[Thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{de}[Thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{re}[Thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{ex}[Thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{cor}[Thm]{Corollary}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\newcommand{\BibUrl}{\url}
%\def\be{\begin{equation}
%\def\ee\end{equation}}
%\def\bea{\begin{eqnarray}
%\def\eea{\end{eqnarray}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Complex Numbers}
\end{document}
```

How to get the simple border line and boundary line between columns?

Comment: [`\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}\setlength{\columnsep}{3em}`](https://texblog.org/2016/01/25/adding-a-column-separator-line-and-extra-space-between-columns-in-latex/)

Comment: @Jojo How to get the border line?